# Storing an Object into a Text File

Tags: file, dart, flutter, save

I need to store a list in a text file as the object itself. 
I can currently store strings in a text file by doing this by using `path_provider`

```
void save() async{
  final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  String path = '${directory.path}/newfile.txt';
  final file = File(path);
  await file.writeAsString(arr.join());
}
```

but is it possible to store the List itself so I can access the list as is after I open up the file after a restart occurs.

Comment: No. You have to open file every time your app starts.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best solution to save variables in the text files. You might need a database solution as your list goes bigger. But for a list that has couple of values inside, you are fine. Here is a simple code that reads/writes the list from a file.

```
  String specialChar = '*';

  Future<void> save(List<String> list) async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = '${directory.path}/newfile.txt';
    final file = File(path);
    await file.writeAsString(list.join(specialChar));
  }

  Future<List<String>> read() async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = '${directory.path}/newfile.txt';
    final file = File(path);
    String raw = await file.readAsString();
    return raw.split(specialChar);
  }
```

You can also consider using `shared_preferences` library. It's a simple solution for storing simple key-value paired data.

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize objects and then store them into files.

Start reading this.

https://www.dartlang.org/articles/libraries/serialization